# How to load index page while splash screen loading in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm implementing app in phonegap. I'm using google map service in my application.

google map api script included in my index page.
when network slow, at the time showing white screen for 5 sec after splash screen.
because of problem with loading map api script.

I tried to remove white screen in all possible ways but not possible,
my requirement is, while splash screen loading i need to load index page.
after splash screen without white screen,open the main page.

I included map api in indea file bellow way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

config file for showing splash screen

```
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

I'm using cordova 3.6.3 version.

Comment: To be honest, I have tried many tricks but none of them worked for delaying splash screen. All I had to do was to create image pages.

Answer (score -2):

Consider using Google Maps API plugin.
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Sometimes is hard to configure, but I think it will resolve your problem.